# Join two defaultdicts in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, defaultdict

I parsed a huge database of bibliographic records (about 20 million records). Each record has unique ID field, a set of authors and a set of term/keywords that describe main content of the  bibliographic record. For example, a typical bibliographic record looks like:

```
ID: 001
Author: author1
Author: author2
Term: term1
Term: term2
```

First, I create two `defaultdict`s to store authors and terms:

```
d1 = defaultdict(lambda : defaultdict(list))
d2 = defaultdict(lambda : defaultdict(list))
```

Next, I populate authors:

```
d1['id001'] = ['author1', 'author2'] 
d1['id002'] = ['author3'] 
d1['id003'] = ['author1', 'author4']
```

and keywords:

```
d2['id001'] = ['term1', 'term2']  
d2['id002'] = ['term2', 'term3']
d2['id003'] = ['term4']
```

The problem is how to join these two dictionaries to obtain data object which links between authors and terms directly:

```
author1|term1,term2,term4
author2|term1,term2
author3|term2,term3
author4|term4
```

I have two questions:

- Is proposed approach appropriate or should I store/represent data in some other way?
- Could you please roughly suggest how to join both dictionaries?

Comment: Can you have one multi-level dict and store author and term in the same dict? Like d['id001']["authors"]=['author1', 'author2']; and d['id001']["terms"] = ['term1', 'term2']

Comment: @Raghuram Yes, that would be fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one way. Note, as demonstrated below, you do not need to use nested dictionaries or a `defaultdict` for your initial step.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d1 = {}
d2 = {}

d1['id001'] = ['author1', 'author2'] 
d1['id002'] = ['author3'] 
d1['id003'] = ['author1', 'author4'] 

d2['id001'] = ['term1', 'term2']  
d2['id002'] = ['term2', 'term3']
d2['id003'] = ['term4']

res = defaultdict(list)

for ids in set(d1) & set(d2):
    for v in d1[ids]:
        res[v].extend(d2[ids])

res = {k: sorted(v) for k, v in res.items()}

# {'author1': ['term1', 'term2', 'term4'],
#  'author2': ['term1', 'term2'],
#  'author3': ['term2', 'term3'],
#  'author4': ['term4']}
```

Comment: "you do not need to use nested dictionaries" you mean "you do not need to use default dictionaries"

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, Both! OP has `d1 = defaultdict(lambda : defaultdict(list))`.

Comment: yes, because OP maybe hoped that he could use the original dicts to build the results. Nice solution, concise and all :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, thks, lots of ways to do this stuff.

Answer (score 3):

The key of those problems is to build temporary dictionaries "properly oriented" from the existing ones. Once that is done, it's much clearer (and the complexity is good thanks to proper dict lookup)

Here's my solution:

First create a dict author => ids from `d1`.

Then create the result (a dict author => terms). Loop in the created author => ids dict and populate the result with the flattened values of `d2`.

```
d1=dict()
d2=dict()

d1['id001'] = ['author1', 'author2']
d1['id002'] = ['author3']
d1['id003'] = ['author1', 'author4']

d2['id001'] = ['term1', 'term2']
d2['id002'] = ['term2', 'term3']
d2['id003'] = ['term4']

import collections

authors_id = collections.defaultdict(list)
for k,v in d1.items():
    for a in v:
        authors_id[a].append(k)

print(dict(authors_id)) # convert to dict for clearer printing


authors_term = collections.defaultdict(list)
for k,v in authors_id.items():
    for a in v:
        for i in d2[a]:
            authors_term[k].append(i)

print(dict(authors_term)) # convert to dict for clearer printing
```

result:

```
{'author4': ['id003'], 'author3': ['id002'], 'author1': ['id001', 'id003'], 'author2': ['id001']}
{'author3': ['term2', 'term3'], 'author4': ['term4'], 'author1': ['term1', 'term2', 'term4'], 'author2': ['term1', 'term2']}
```

Comment: Small note. Not sure if sorting matters, but *if it does* this solution assumes that term4 for an author comes after term1 when cycling ids. [Trivially fixed though.]

Comment: this solution is more a "first pass" solution, simpler to comprehend, your has less passes, clearly more polished and more performant.